# Как расположить блоки div с заданными условиями?

Tags: css, html, position

Есть 2 блока, высота которых зависит от содержимого.

**Необходимо:**

1. Второй блок должен занимать всю доступную высоту экрана.
2. При переполнении он должен растягиваться.

Не могу сообразить, как такое можно реализовать.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я правильно понял идею?
У меня получилось только в виде таблиц:

```css
html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}
.wrapper {height: 100%; display: table;}
.inner {display:table-row;}
.fill {height:100%; background: #99aa99; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
  <div class="inner fill">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, отличный вариант, спасибо. А то я уже и флексбоксом пробовал..

Answer (score 1):

В стиль второго блока `div`, добавь атрибут `min-height` со значением `100%`.

**Но это будет работать только если** атрибут `position` равен `fixed` или `absolute`. Иначе в стиле главного тега `body` атрибуты `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, `padding-top` и `padding-bottom` должны быть равны `0px`.

Comment: Что-то недопонимаю. http://codepen.io/light-flight/pen/BKKdYa

Comment: @Георгий а так понятно? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyyvPv

Comment: Нет. Высота второго блока занимает не "доступную высоту экрана", а всю. Под "доступной" я подразумеваю высота вьюпорта минус высота первого блока, содержимое которого неизвестно.

Comment: Изменил вопрос. Если вы всё сделаете так, как я ответил, то, насколько правильно я понимаю ваш вопрос, должно всё работать.